# CDI Instance Producer

Tags: java, cdi, javabeans, java-ee-8

The instances passed to my producer does represent effective beans?

```
@Qualif1
@Prodcues
B qualif1(@Any Instance<B> instances){
    return instances.select(B1.class).get(); // Select instance of B1 which extends B
}
```

I am wondering if instances are already beans or only the selected one will be a bean managed by the container?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not depend on using `instances`, but on the scopes of the beans. A call to `get` works like any other injection point: if you `get` a prototype bean, a new instance of the bean gets created. If you `get` an eager singleton - it is already created before you call `get`.

It seems like your question stems from mixing up beans and instances of beans: the former are definitions (and are all, in a sense "managed" by the container), the latter are instances (which are in the direct sense "managed").

The ladder of abstraction goes like this:

class -> bean -> instance

So the "bean" is neither a class (although in some projects every bean is also a class) nor an instance (although in some projects every bean is also an instance).

Personally, I blame Spring for blurring the boundaries between the three, by encouraging usage of eager singletons for practically everything.